# JS, what syntax is this? "var3 = (var1 > var2) ? var1 : var2"

Tags: javascript, syntax

I found a script using the following syntax:

```
var variable3 = (Math.abs(variable1)>Math.abs(variable2)) ? variable1 : variable2;
```

As far, as I get it, that seems to compare if `variable1` is bigger than `variable2`. Then output, if yes, `variable1`, otherwise `variable2`?

I couldn't find any description and this seems to be something handy, could someone explain it?

THX!

Comment: see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (and is the only ternary operator in JavaScript).

It this case it is equivalent to

```
if((Math.abs(variable1)>Math.abs(variable2)))
{
   variable3= variable1;
}
else
{
   variable3 = variable2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its called the "Ternary Operator" Its another way to do a simple in-line if statement and return the value to a variable from it.

See [Wikipedia for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 0):

it's similar to

```
if(Math.abs(variable1)>Math.abs(variable2))
    var variable3 =  variable1;
else
    var variable3 =  variable2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a ternary conditional operator (also called a `?` mark operator). This is used instead of `if` statement, but it is as flexible as `if` statement.